# Binding Form Data on Browser Back Spring MVC

Tags: spring, forms, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm Developing a application using Spring MVC + Hibernate. So It have a function that have a confirmation screen before complete the task. 
In here After submit the main input form it creates a form submit. Then it redirect to confirmation screen and ask for users to review it. after reviewing user can proceed it for last step.

If user want to change values then i put a back button on confirmation.
back button manually and bind all the data and redirect it to first page. It is working.

But i want to know how to **bind the data** back to first form when user press **browser back button** ?

Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: What is the problem here? Whenever you press the browser back button, it will have all the data that you have entered previously.

Comment: @javafan No, Here im using redirect with all the data for go to confirmation button. So when we are getting back with browser back button all the data will be cleared.